# Como evitar problemas luego de que la rama que uso de upstream tuvo un force-push que reescribió su historia?

Tags: git, git-push, git-rebase

Tengo una rama `ramaX` que utiliza la rama `un-remoto/rama-base` como su *upstream branch*. La historia de esa rama fue reescrita (con un force-push) y ahora no se qué hacer para que mi rama se monte sobre esa nueva rama. Cuales problemas tengo si me quedo en la vieja rama? Y como puedo montarme sobre la rama nueva con el menor esfuerzo posible?

Answer (score 0):

El mayor problema que esto trae es que debes deshacerte de las *viejas* revisiones que fueron reescritas.

Si te quedaras sobre la rama actual como si nada hubiera pasado, al empujar tu rama para mezclarla en la rama principal del proyecto, estarías incluyendo esas revisions que ya no forman parte de dicha rama y es **mas que probable** que no quieras tener dichas revisiones en tu rama porque entonces **para qué se reescribió la historia?**

Si intentaras hacer un simple rebase de `ramaX` para montarte en la nueva rama (por ejemplo, `git checkout ramaX; git fetch un-remoto; git rebase un-remoto/rama-base`), git no solo llevaría las revisiones que forman parte de la ramaX *en sí* (o sea, tu desarrollo), sino también las revisiones que **fueron reescritas**, cosa que no quieres que suceda. Eso hace que un simple `git pull` (con rebase o con merge) no sea una opción.

Puede parecer como que es una situación bastante dificultosa para salir adelante pero en realidad es muy sencillo salir del atolladero. Este es el procedimiento:

## The Pledge

Mira la historia de tu rama actual y busca la última revisión de la **upstream branch** vieja (es decir, no de la historia reescrita sino de la historia vieja) que forma parte de la historia de tu rama (se puede hacer con `git log`, `gitk` o algún otro método). Llamemos a esa revision `vieja-rev-base`.

Has un fetch del repositorio remoto para obtener lo último de la nueva rama base

```
git fetch un-remoto # ajusta el nombre del remoto a tu ambiente, obviamente
```

## The Turn

Tenemos que pedirle a git que haga un rebase pero solo de las revisiones que forman parte de tu feature branch y no de la antigua rama base.

```
git rebase --onto un-remoto/rama-base vieja-rev-base ramaX
```

## The Prestige

Listo, ya puedes seguir trabajando como si nada hubiera pasado.